# Apple automator video tutorials

Tags: macos, automator

Where can I find some Automator video tutorials ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After some deep search on google I found this:

http://automator.us/leopard/video/index.html

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube is always the first place I go when looking for tutorial videos.

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Automator+tutorials&search_type=

Answer (score 0):

There are some good at [MacBreak Dev](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/macbreak_dev) with Sal Soghoian. This are the numbers 5, 7 and 9-12. Also 13 contains a little bit Automator stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Really good podcast series from peachpit.  "Mac Automation Made Simple"

http://macautomation.pearson.libsynpro.com/rss

There are over 20 episodes now.